# Outwardly beauty or outward beauty?

Tags: word-choice, diction, derivation

Which one is more grammatically correct?

In my opinion, "outwardly beauty" sounds better but I wanted to be sure it's grammatically correct.

If neither is correct, what is alternative? I considered "external appearance" but that doesn't sound as nice to me

Comment: Please give a complete sentence that contains the phrase in the way you want to use it. English is a context-dependent language.  Both of your phrases could occur in valid English sentences. However they would mean different things.

Comment: Usually "beauty" is a noun, so the modifier is an adjective.  *outward beauty*.  On the other hand, a modifier to an adjective is an adverb.  *outwardly beautiful*

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - I can’t think of a case where “Outwardly beauty” works.  Her outward beauty could be exceptional.   She could be outwardly beautiful.  Oh, maybe something like: “Outwardly, beauty was defined by mascara and eyeliner, but inwardly...”  but that requires a comma.

Comment: @Jim - It's a fair point. However, in my book, "outwardly" can be an adjective.  Here's a list of adjectives ending in "ly".  https://polyglotclub.com/wiki/Language/English/Grammar/Adjectives-ending-in-ly -  Example: "Her outwardly beauty was something to behold."

Comment: @chaslyfromUK -  Ok,  interesting.  For me, AmE, that would be ungrammatical.

Comment: I must admit that its not common usage!

Comment: It seemed that outwardly beauty was his only concern, even though inwardly he considered intelligence to be far more important.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, the vast majority of the words on your linked listed are formed from a noun with the -ly suffix, which doesn't describe *outwardly*. Several of the others (crassly, enormously) I struggle to come up with any sentence that uses them as adjectives (and a couple of dictionaries I checked list them as adverbs only). Only *deadly* and *seemly* match the form of adj + -ly, which is  a pretty small list.

Comment: @HotLicks In your example, surely, _outwardly_ introduces the next clause and could be followed by a comma; it doesn't describe _beauty_.

Comment: @HotLicks if you want to parse "outwardly" as an adjective describing "beauty" in your example, you should also parse "inwardly" as an adjective describing "he" :)

Comment: @alephzero - Why do you think "outwardly" is modifying "beauty" rather than "was"?

Comment: "Outwardly beauty" is ungrammatical; outwardly is purely an adverb. Why it might sound good to some ears is that there exist "ly" adjectives like "orderly", "brotherly", "friendly", "early", "curly" and "easterly".  And, *vice versa*, "outward" doesn't follow a common pattern for adjectives. There are other "-ward" adjectives like "untoward behavior" or "forward direction".

Comment: @chaslyfromUK "outwardly" seems like a malapropism perpetrated by someone who is not aware of the plethora of adjectives ending in "ward", which include "outward". It's a rather backwardly usage, arising from an untowardly attitude toward the language. Sorry for using "malapropism" wrongly, but I like it two-and-a-half times as much as that author liked "outwardly".

Comment: Okay, I give in!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Not so fast; that appears "cowardly"!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first phrase is not quite correct.

Depending how you want to use it, you want either a noun or an adjectival phrase.

As a noun:

> She *has* **outward beauty**.

As an adjectival phrase:

> She *is* **outwardly** ***beautiful***.

---

Since a complete sentence wasn't used in the question, it's not possible to tell which of those two would be appropriate in the context you're thinking of.

Answer (score 5):

In this case "outward beauty" would be more correct, as "outward" is an adjective referring to "beauty", a noun, although consider "outer beauty", as it sounds more natural in my opinion.